# how to pick single lines from a pull request

Tags: git, github

On github I get a pull request for a translation file. I.e. this pull request has about some hundrets of changed lines. 
https://github.com/privacyidea/privacyidea/pull/493/files

Each line for a single translation. But it is only one commit.
But To me only 50% of the translations are good.
I would like to cycle through each changed line and either fetch it or drop it.

If I pull this pull request the complete commit will be in my local branch. What would be the recommended workflow to only merge parts of the commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [interactive staging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging) go through all patches [and select which you need](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging#Staging-Patches) and then commit and merge selected changes.

Comment: Interactive staging looks like the thing I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure to mark correct answer so others could find an answer faster and answerer will get extra points.

Answer (score 1):

In git, commit is the smallest unit. It is not possible to break commit into lines and accept only a subset of these lines.

Recommended workflow is that you put comments on the Pull Request flagging all wrong translations based on which the initial author of Pull Request adds another commit with the corrections suggested and then you accept the whole commit.

Comment: The originial pull-requester seemed not to care. Thanks for your note!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would deal with this is to simply pull the feature branch on which your colleague made the bad translations, fix whatever I did not like, and update the pull request by pushing.  It is up to you how you do this, e.g. adding a new "fix" commit, amending the last commit, etc.

I don't know of a way to do a partial merge through GitHub's web interface, and you should not need to do this in any case.

I am assuming that you have edit rights on this feature branch.